# order of cells in loop "for each cell"

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, ms-word

I'm wondering if there is a rule to know in wich order the loop will be done ?

Is there a way to change it ?

Let's say I have multiple ranges on multiple sheets on multiple workbooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are always rules for loops to run. You could make some experiments but I'll give you some information (as far as I remember).

**Workbooks:** the order is from the first opened/created to last opened/created.

**Worksheets/Sheets:** the order if from left to right as you could see them in application.

**Cells (in ranges):** it goes first in row from left to right, next move to next row (as we read and write in English).

*Three other examples:*

**Comments in Excel sheet:** based on address of cell where the comment is located, in the order the loop goes with cells (see above).

**Comments in Word document:** from the beginning of the document, in the order of appearance.

**Bookmarks in MS Word:** alphabetically by bookmark's name.

---

***Edit on 8th August 2013***

I've just found something interesting regarding order of bookmarks in Word document. In fact there are two orders:

**1.** This loop:

```
    Dim BM As Bookmark
    For Each BM In ActiveDocument.Content.Bookmarks
    Next
```

will iterate in order of appearance  of bookmarks in `Document Content (Range)`

**2.** While this Loop:

```
    Dim BM As Bookmark
    For Each BM In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    Next
```

will iterate in alphabetical order based on bookmark names.

---

When using `For...Next` loop you can reverse the order using `Step minus` parameter.

It's quite easy to make experiments and I could admit- quite often it's important to know the loop iteration order.

Answer (score 1):

If you use indexes rather than for each loops, you can define 'step' which tells it how to loop through the indexes:

```
Sub test_forloop()

Dim rng As Range Dim i As Integer Dim strOut As String

Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count Step 1
    strOut = strOut & rng.Cells(i).Address Next

MsgBox strOut

strOut = ""
' Now do it stepping backwards

For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    strOut = strOut & rng.Cells(i).Address Next

MsgBox strOut

End Sub
```

This will work the same with sheets and workbooks if they are members of the same collection (use `Worksheets(<index>)`).