# VBA: Why are For Each loops faster than For loops?

Tags: vba, performance, for-loop, foreach

In VBA, it's known that the `For Each` loop will iterate through a `Collection` faster than the `For` loop, with the difference in time between the two looping methods increasing exponentially(?) as a function of the `Collection` size.  (This assumes that iteration is "in order" over the `Collection` members of course.)

*Why* is it faster though?  How can the `For Each` loop access items faster than via their indices in a `Collection`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467043/11683?

Comment: @GSerg thanks for the link.  From that post, I got to a site that seems to go into heavy detail on the inner workings of VBA, so perhaps I can find an answer there.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem recently with a collection of instances of some class, and, indeed, `for each` is further faster than `for`. I ran some tests to know why and what I found is that the extra delay using `for` is due find the specified item among all itens in collection.

**The test**:
I create a simple class containing just an integer as public field and nothing more. Then, was created 100,000 instances of this class and added in a collection

```
Dim mClass As cls
Dim col As New Collection   

For i = 1 To 100000
    Set mClass = New cls
    mClass.a = 1
    Call col.Add(mClass)
    Set mClass = Nothing
Next i
```

then I measured the time to run each one of the following block of code

**1) For each (time ~0.95s)**

```
For Each obj In col
    obj.a = 1
Next
```

**2a) For through all elements of collection (time ~95s)**

```
For i = 1 To 100000
    Set mClass = col(i)
    mClass.a = 1
    Set mClass= Nothing
Next i
```

**2b) For only the first element (time ~0.15s)**

```
For i = 1 To 100000
    Set mClass = col(1)
    mClass.a = 1
    Set mClass = Nothing
Next i
```

**2c) For only the last element(time ~180s)**

```
For i = 1 To 100000
    Set mClass = col(100000)
    mClass.a = 1
    Set mClass = Nothing
Next i
```

**3) allocating and deallocating memory (time ~0.72s)**

```
For i = 1 To 100000
    Set mClass = New cls
        mClass.a = 1
    Set mClass = Nothing
Next i
```

**4) using another instance out of collection (time ~0.05s)**

```
Dim mclass2 As cls
Set mclass2 = New cls
For i = 1 To 100000
    Set mClass = mclass2
    mClass.a = 1
    Set mClass = Nothing
Next i
```

The time it takes works more in relative basis than absolute one and give us an idea where time is spended.

Comment: The 2a, 2b, and 2c tests are interesting.  There's a semi-linear increase in time taken across the tests, which could be a key, just as you suggested.  The question now becomes something like, "How does the For Each loop iterate over items?"

Answer (score -1):

Your presumption that `For Each` is faster than `For 1 To` is wrong. Both loop through a set of numbers which they can do at identical speed.

In the `For Each` variant the number identifies objects in a collection, such as Sheets(1), Sheets(2), Sheets(3) etc. These sheets aren't loaded or even accessed in the loop. They are just referenced.

By comparison, `For i = 1 to 3: Set Ws = Sheets(i)` would just create references to the sheets.

Accordingly, a difference develops from what you do with the referenced objects, not from the way you reference them. `For Each` often appears as the somewhat simpler code. But if you wish to refer to `ActiveSheet.Cells(3)` you do need to know whether this will be C1 or A3 and the apparent greater ease of coding comes at the cost of transparency. I treat it as a matter of taste.

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim R As Long
Arr = Range("A1:A20")
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
    Debug.Print Arr(R, 1)
Next R
```

is much faster than

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Set Rng = Range("A1:A20")
For Each Cell in Rng
    Debug.Print Cell.Value
Next Cell
```

But this is because the second code references the sheet 20 times against the first snippet's once. Perhaps it's this difference that you have been reading about.

Comment: Note also that in `For Each Cell in Rng`, there is no order specified (nor documented) and the cells could be referenced in any order.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie https://stackoverflow.com/a/16866876/11683

Comment: @Variatus I understand the point that you are making about minimizing the number of interactions between VBA and the Sheet, but my question is about pure VBA: explicitly `Collections`.  

I did a test iteration using both of the methods through a `Collection` with 70,000 items.  Each item was added to a total.   The `For Each` was approximately 1000 times faster than the `For` loop (22ms vs 22s to run, respectively).

Comment: @TehDrunkenSailor For your test to have a bearing on my analysis we should look at what the collection consisted of and the "items" that were added. The difference you found is about the difference I would expect between reading a cell and adding its value to a total or reading an array. So, if you tested a collection of cells then your result would prove that `For Each Cell In Range.Cells` creates an array of cell values (seems strange). It wouldn't prove that the collection is accessed faster.

Comment: @Variatus Apologies, I will be clearer this time.  My test did not interact with Excel in any way; it was pure VBA.  I created a collection containing 70,000 items (the numbers 1 through 70,000) in VBA.  (Not a collection of cells.)  Then, I iterated over each member of the collection and added the value of the member to a total.  I did this iteration using both a `For Each` and a `For` loop.  Since both loops were performing the exact same task, I want to know why one is able to complete faster than the other.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks for the link, but note that that is just empirical determined and not formally documented. Could change the next release.

Comment: @TehDrukungenSailor It isn't exactly the same calculation. It isn't possible to set up a collection of numbers. So, I presume you set up an array and went through the elements of the array with For, like `Total = Total + Coll(i)`. I repeated that with  Each `Total = Total + Arr` where Arr  is a member of the collection. I admit, the difference is stunning (14 secs against 0.004 seconds) but the explanation is in the difference of handling the array that holds the numbers. IMHO it doesn't support a generalized conclusion that collections are faster. Interesting nevertheless!